# How do I make a persistent camera between scene changes with MRTK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I just updated to MRTK RC2, and up until now, a persistent camera has not been possible without some tweaking. There used to be a check-button for persistency, but aside from that I also had to enter the FocusProvider.cs script, and in the "FindOrCreateUIRaycastCamera" I would set the MainCamera to be the parent of the UIRayCastCamera. I'm pretty sure this was also the setup in the beta, but ever since it was randomly no longer a part of the MixedRealityPlayspace camera, it's been hard to change the scene in Unity.

Now my little quickfix does not seem to work anymore, the UIRaycastCamera will be a child of the MainCamera, but on scene change it disappears and from there nothing works. I made a script myself that makes the camera DontDestroyOnLoad, but as previously mentioned the UIRayCastCamera magically disappears, and a lot of the MRTK stuff seemingly relies on this camera.

I'm almost certain there must be a better way to have a persistent camera throughout the scenes, than what I've been doing up until now. How would I go about it?

Comment: See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes for possible answers to this problem. I usually use a static script for sharing data between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using additive loading to create a persistent camera. You would start by creating a manager scene with your MRTK instance and main camera. This would be the first thing you load, and you would never unload it. Then you would additively load / unload other scenes as needed.

For most apps this can be accomplished with Unity's scene manager without much fuss. A Scene System service is also in development for more complex apps and will be available soon. You can preview it in the development branch.